# Is there a git hook, similar to pre-commit, that would run for every new commit that is about to be created with git rebase?

Tags: git, automation, rebase, githooks, git-rebase

### Context:

I have a `pre-commit` hook installed for all my local repositories.

Basically what my hook does is running all the unit tests, exiting with 0 when all tests passes and exiting with non-zero when at least one test failed or when there is no test.

So `git commit` creates the commit only when **all** unit tests are successful.
Otherwise the commit is abort and I must fix my code and/or my tests, but I must make my tests pass, then retry to commit...

With this setup I know that every commit I created have been properly tested and that I can safely push them to the remote.

### Problem:

But I only have one issue with this setup : `git rebase`.  I do a lot of `git rebase` with my locals branches.

When I rebase a branch I would like to run unit tests on every new commit about to be created.  I don't find any documentation about this specific use case.
I know that a `pre-rebase` hook exists but it will only fires before the rebase starts, giving a chance to abort the rebase.  It does not fire for every new commit that are going to be created from that rebase.

### Question:

Is there a hook, or a technique, or anything else that can help me automate the process of rebasing a branch **and** at the same time give me the confidence that all the unit tests have been run on every new commit created?
It should work with `git rebase` and `git rebase --interactive` as well.

Basically i think `git rebase` should run the `pre-commit` hook when it is about to create a new commit.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. With interactive rebase you can use `--exec` to insert `exec` commands after each cherry-pick, and use `git commit --amend` as needed along the way for failing tests, but it's not automatic.

Comment: i heard that pre-applypatch could be use for that.

Comment: Aha. Pre-applypatch should handle the non-interactive rebase case. Cherry-pick (invoked from interactive rebase) won't go through it but perhaps you could use the pre-commit hook for those (it will run unless you've suppressed that too).

Comment: @torek Could you maybe make an answer out of this comment, expending it  with some more detailed information of which commands would trigger these hooks and which would not? (I'm surprised this is not answered yet. Is using hooks for unit tests really such uncommon practice...)

Comment: @NO_NAME: it seems to me to be uncommon (the usual method these days is a CI system, not hooks in a local repository at all). One issue with using hooks is that they've traditionally been kind of weak and poorly defined. In the last two or three years, some work has gone into making the hook code much more systematic, and somethings may have changed since Feb 2020; I'd have to look closely and think hard to turn this into a real answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> When I rebase a branch I would like to run unit tests on every new commit about to be created.

Locally, the [client-side `pre-applypatch`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_email_hooks) could be used:

The next hook to run when applying patches via [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) is `pre-applypatch`.

Somewhat confusingly, it is run after the patch is applied but before a commit is made, so you can use it to inspect the snapshot before making the commit.
You can run tests or otherwise inspect the working tree with this script.
If something is missing or the tests don’t pass, exiting non-zero aborts the `git am` script without committing the patch.

However, there could be case where you do not want that hook to be triggered (during a manual `git am` for instance, not part of a rebase)

For that:

With Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), conditionally skip the `pre-applypatch` and `applypatch-msg` hooks when applying patches with '[`git am`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b242e89dff9cc5c736bcf3629df9564a98ff23db/Documentation/git-am.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am))</sup>.

See [commit 566902f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/566902f2db3bdad9be7fb083c713f0d21acf111e) (30 Nov 2022) by [Thierry Reding (`thierryreding`)](https://github.com/thierryreding).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b242e89](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b242e89dff9cc5c736bcf3629df9564a98ff23db), 16 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`am`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/566902f2db3bdad9be7fb083c713f0d21acf111e): allow passing --no-verify flag
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Thierry Reding</sup>

> The [`git-am --no-verify`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/566902f2db3bdad9be7fb083c713f0d21acf111e/Documentation/git-am.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am))</sup> flag is analogous to the same flag passed to git-commit.
> It bypasses the pre-applypatch and applypatch-msg hooks if they are enabled.
>
> `'git am' [--signoff] [--keep] [--[no-]keep-cr] [--[no-]utf8] [--no-verify]`

`git am` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/566902f2db3bdad9be7fb083c713f0d21acf111e/Documentation/git-am.txt#L141-L146):

> ### `-n`
>
> ### `--no-verify`
>
> By default, the pre-applypatch and applypatch-msg hooks are run.
> When any of `--no-verify` or `-n` is given, these are bypassed.